# Verify that an implicit equation is the solution to the differential equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, problem-solving, differential

Verify that
\begin{equation}
a.\;x^3+y^3-3xy=0,\; \mathbb{R}_{x\neq2^{2/3}}
\end{equation}
is the solution to
\begin{equation}
b.\;(y^2-x)y' - y+x^2=0
\end{equation}
As we know the function g(x) of a. is not easily attainable, therefore we resort to stating one graphically. Such that at $2^{2/3}$ does not exist meaning it makes a jump.
[image: ![Text](https://stackoverflow.com/[![image.jpg][1]][1])]

The book I'm reading says that if we implicitly differentiate a. then it agrees with b. and hence the definition of the solution is met.

Definition of solution:
Implicit Solution of ODE
f(x,y) is the implicit solution of a differential equation:
\begin{equation}
F(x, y, y',\dots,y^{(n)})=0,\: D
\end{equation}
on the domain D if it defines a function $g(x)$ in D such that
f[x,g(x)]=0 which
\begin{equation}
F[x, g(x) g(x)',\dots,g(x)^{(n)}]=0
\end{equation}

I don't understand the logic behind the author's assertion and the definition.

Comment: This is not a function.  It is just a relation.

Comment: An implicit function is also a term for an implicit equation. It's not an actual function. I've edited the title to make that clear.

Comment: @JackFrosher okay.  Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the proposed DE as follows:
\begin{align*}
(y^{2} - x)y' - y + x^{2} = 0 & \Longleftrightarrow y^{2}y' - xy' - y + x^{2} = 0\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow y^{2}y' - (xy)' = -x^{2}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow \frac{y^{3}}{3} - xy = -\frac{x^{3}}{3} + c_{0}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{3} + y^{3} - 3xy = c
\end{align*}

which leads exactly to the implicit equation that defines $y$ when one considers $c = 0$.

Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to rewrite

\begin{equation}
\;x^3+y^3-3xy=0
\end{equation}

in the form

$$ (x+y)^3-3x^2y-3xy^2-3xy=0 $$

When you take $\dfrac{d}{dx}$ of both sides you will see that all terms subtract out except

$$ x^2+y^2y^\prime-y-xy^\prime=0 $$

Comment: How does this manipulation indicate a logical satisfaction of the definition.

Comment: The idea behind the definition is to expand the concept of 'solution' as it applies to a differential equation. Generally speaking, a solution of an algebraic equation is of the form $x=\{some number set\}$. The definition is merely  acknowledging that the solution of a DE needn't be of the form $y=f(x)$ but can be of the form $g(x,y)=0$. At least that is my take on the exercise.

Comment: Oh, ok got it. Thank You.